# precision and scale in @column

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity, ddl

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875149/what-does-the-length-attribute-do-when-set-on-the-column-jpa-annontation) I read that length in @column is only for generated DDL. Is this true for precision and scale?

```
    @Column(precision = 15, scale = 5)
    private Integer myField;
```

If so: How to define precision and scale for JPA-validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this:

```
@Column
@Digits(integer = 15, fraction = 5)
private Integer myField;
```

Answer (score 1):

The JPA javadocs and spec (links on [this page](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/api.html)) make it clear that these values are for schema generation ONLY. They are also not part of the the Bean Validation standard, so nothing to do with "validation".

Comment: please add (exact) references to the spec/javadoc, might be helpful for @Chris311

Comment: So I can only define this constraint on the db (with NUMBER(15,5))?

Comment: For an Integer field a scale will likely be of little use (depending on the DB). Some DBs don't even support precision.