# Getting status 500 error "Internal Server Error" while running SpringBoot & POSTMAN

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot

I am new to `SpringBoot` and `Postman` and just started learning Java I was following a tutorial, but I keep getting the following error when I try to *POST* using `POSTMAN` after running my files on `SpringBoot`:
[image: Error in POSTMAN]

I have double checked the database and that is running fine, I am also not getting any errors on `SpringBoot`.

LOG from SpringBoot:

```
2023-01-20T17:57:07.313Z[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m8208[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-5][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.advanced.app1.model.Employee.firstName] with root cause

org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.advanced.app1.model.Employee.firstName
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:653) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:283) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:737) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:721) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy96.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:307) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy96.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:610) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy100.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.advanced.app1.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl.saveEmployee(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.advanced.app1.controller.EmployeeController.saveEmployee(EmployeeController.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

```
 {
     "timestamp": "2023-01-20T12:47:38.113+00:00", 
     "status": 500, 
     "error": "Internal Server Error", 
     "path": "/api/employees" 
 }
```

My `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.advanced</groupId>
    <artifactId>sprintboot-advanced</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>sprintboot-advanced</name>
    <description>Sprinboot Advanced</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Main:

```
package com.advanced.app1;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SprintbootAdvanced1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SprintbootAdvanced1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
package com.advanced.app1.controller;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus; 
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.advanced.app1.model.Employee;
import com.advanced.app1.service.EmployeeService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/employees")
public class EmployeeController {
    
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeService) {
        super();
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }
    
    // build REST API
    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(employeeService.saveEmployee(employee), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
package com.advanced.app1.exception;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String resourceName;
    private String fieldName;
    private Object fieldValue;
    
    public ResourceNotFoundException(String resourceName, String fieldName, Object fieldValue) {
        super(String.format("%s not found with %s : '%s'", resourceName, fieldName, fieldValue));
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.fieldValue = fieldValue;
    }
    
    public String getResourceName() {
        return resourceName;
    }
    
    public String getFieldName() {
        return fieldName;
    }
    
    public Object getFieldValue() {
        return fieldValue;
    }   
}
```

Model:

```
package com.advanced.app1.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.advanced.app1.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;   
import com.advanced.app1.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

Service:

```
package com.advanced.app1.service;

import com.advanced.app1.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeService {

    Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee);
}
```

ServiceImpl:

```
package com.advanced.app1.service.impl;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;  
import com.advanced.app1.model.Employee;
import com.advanced.app1.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import com.advanced.app1.service.EmployeeService;

@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService{

    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    
    public EmployeeServiceImpl(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        super();
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }

}
```

`application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Headers for request and return `POSTMAN`:
[image: Headers]

Comment: @Muhammad_786 those look correct.  So, in your controller, add a simple print to verify that you're getting what you expect.  Since you're using Lombok, you can simply do something like, `System.out.println(employee);` in the first line of the controller

Comment: @lane.maxwell I have added that would you like me to show the console from spring tool?

Comment: You could add an `org.springframework.ui.Model` as an parameter to your RestController endpoint and take a look, on what postman is providing you because something is wrong with the mapping. Moreover, I would add a NewEmployeeDto class with the given three fields as Strings and @NonNull and let Spring map to it.

Answer (score 3):

You say you're not getting and errors in your Spring Boot log, but you've posted a stack trace, which is the best type of error you could hope for. In fact, it tells you exactly what the problem is:

> org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.advanced.app1.model.Employee.firstName

Your entity does not have "firstName" marked as nullable

```
@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
```

Somehow, your Employee entity is not being populated with the data from your POST request. This can happen if the deserialization can't "automatically" map from your JSON fields to your `Employee` object fields.

One possible reason is that you do not have any getters or setters defined on your Entity. I see you're using `lombok` for this, but I would suggest at least for now ruling out any issue with this not working with Spring's framework and manually generating these methods directly.

You're also writing directly from the REST API into a database Entity. While this isn't strictly a problem, it's not a best practice and can sometimes lead to weird behaviour. I'd recommend creating a model object (POJO) specifically intended for use in your REST interface, and then map to an entity in your Repository.

Comment: Issue is that my employee entity does have  @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false) as you can see from the question aswell.

Comment: @Muhammad_786, yes, but that would only be a problem if the data you are trying to save is `null`. Since your post request clearly has data for "firstName", this indicates that the data in your post request is not being mapped into your entity. Try following some of the recommendations above to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The cause of the issue:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-01-22T14:43:44.841+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/api/employees"
}
```

as correctly, mentioned, [Hypino](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75189652/8370915), is inside your provided `entity`:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
}
```

This *implies* that you labeled `first_name` to not being able to have `null` and so `Spring` isn't able to map the `json` request to an object, so `first_name` is always `null`.

In your case:

`nullable = false` means this value can't be `null`.

```
@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
```

this means when creating the schema for the table, it will use the name `"first_name"` as the name and `name = "firstName", nullable = false` means that while saving to the database, if the value is `null`, it will not save and throw an exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value
```

if you were to look at the actual `sql` that is generated.

In the same time, `@Column` only cares about the database, so when you are calling it via a `Rest API`, `Spring` is only caring about the variable name and not the column name.

As result, you have *several* options how to handle it and it really depends on you and your project requirements:

---

**Option #1**

(To use *explicitly* `nullable = true` as the option)

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = true)
    private String first_name;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = true)
    private String last_name;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = true)
    private String email;
}
```

in accordance with the `body` in `Postman` as:

```
{
    "first_name": "testFirstName",
    "last_name": "testLastName",
    "email": "testEmail@gmail.com"
}
```

***Pros***

- you can see right away that it is nullable. This could be useful when you are analyzing the code directly from github for example or you don't know the default value.
- if default value ever changes, you have it set and don't have to worry about it.

***Cons***:

- there is very very small chance that default value ever changes
- it makes code more verbose and that is generaly frowned upon.

`true` is the default option for nullable, so can be omitted. In the absence of a `@Column` annotation with a name, `Hibernate` will create a column using the field name, replacing camel-case with snake-case.

> If you like keeping things explicit - fine.

---

**Option #2**

(To avoid the usage of annotations: `@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false` for specific fields, as attached below)

`Controller` class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/employees")
public class EmployeeController {

    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeService) {
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
        return new ResponseEntity<>
                (employeeService.saveEmployee(employee), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

`ResourceNotFoundException` class:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String resourceName;
    private String fieldName;
    private Object fieldValue;

    public ResourceNotFoundException(String resourceName, String fieldName, Object fieldValue) {
        super(String.format("%s not found with %s : '%s'", resourceName, fieldName, fieldValue));
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.fieldValue = fieldValue;
    }

    public String getResourceName() {
        return resourceName;
    }

    public String getFieldName() {
        return fieldName;
    }

    public Object getFieldValue() {
        return fieldValue;
    }
}
```

`Model` class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String email;
}
```

`Repository`:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

`Service` implementation (*business-logic*):

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    public EmployeeServiceImpl(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        super();
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }
}
```

`Service`:

```
public interface EmployeeService {

    Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee);
}
```

`Main` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootAdvancedApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAdvancedApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and accordingly `database` configuration:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=...
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

As result, you can test via `Postman` using `POST` request as the following:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/employees
```

with `body` as in the example:

```
{
    "firstName": "testFirstName",
    "lastName": "testLastName",
    "email": "testEmail@gmail.com"
}
```

[image]

choosing `raw` & `JSON` as your options.

[image]

*Headers for request*:

[image]

The content of `POM` file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>10</source>
                <target>10</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> If you prefer avoiding boilerplate when you are aware of the defaults - also fine. The key here is keeping the rules consistent throughout the entire project.

---

Additional *`useful`* & *`informative`* links:

1. [Hibernate Tips: What’s the difference between @Column(nullable = false) and @NotNull](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-whats-the-difference-between-column-nullable-false-and-notnull/)
2. [Hibernate @NotNull vs @Column(nullable = false)](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-notnull-vs-nullable)
3. [Hibernate handling of nullable=true in @Column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24002892/8370915)
4. [Does it make sense to write @Column(nullable = true) for entity while using Hibernate?](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjava/comments/10irw2d/comment/j5h2vae/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)