# Usage of @Basic(optional = false) in writing entity class

Tags: java, jpa, orm

Uhm, I have a question regarding the **@Basic(optional = false)** and **@NotNull** notation.

Usually, we would write variables in entity class as below:

**Mock-up code:**

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = USERNAME)
private String userName;
```

The notation above describes that for the field **username** , it would not accept a **NULL** value.

Usually, the **@Basic(optional = false)** notation is followed by **@NotNull** notation , but if I would like to have a field, let's say **userID** , and it is an **Auto-Increment** type , which is also the **Primary Key** , should I just wrote the code as below?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = USERID)
private Integer userID;
```

Or remove the **@Basic(optional = false)** as well?

**Edited**

Latest code:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = USERID)
private Integer userID;
```

One more question, is that only **@Basic(optional = false)** will work same as **@Basic(optional = false)** followed-up by **@NotNull** ?

Code shown as below:

**Code 1**

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = USERNAME)
private String userName;
```

**Code 2**

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = USERNAME)
private String userName;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

no. `@Id` replaces `@Basic` - either use one or the other. `@GeneratedValue` can only accompany `@Id`.

`@NotNull` has nothing to do with JPA and you can place it wherever you want.

more info on NotNull vs Column annotations - as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439504/confusion-notnull-vs-columnnullable-false), NotNull and Column annotation properties come from different places (bean validation vs persistence) and deal with different aspects of the object's lifecycle:

`@NotNull` is a bean validation annotation that specifies that the property must hold some value. hibernate **MAY** check this before persisting your entity into the database, if hibernate-validator integration is enabled in your setup, but may also completely ignore it. various other frameworks along the way (jax-rs implementations in your API layer etc) may also check your bean to validate that @NotNull holds. hibernate **may** also take notice of this annotation when generating the database schema and make the column not nullable, but its in no way required to do so.

`@Column` is a JPA annotation and deals only with how your property is mapped to the database. nothing else. you can make a column not nullable and still pass a null value to hibernate. it will result in a runtime exception from the database when hibernate will try to insert/update your data, but hibernate will not check it in advance.

Comment: thanks, i've edited the code above, and another question has added-in. hope can get feedback from you~

Comment: @MMM - i've expanded my answer, and linked to a more detailed one

Comment: oh, so the main different between them are one is checked in advance before persisting to database while another will return exception after persisting into database if errors occured?

Comment: @MMM - more like one is meant to be checked (at various places, among them is before insertion), and the other is meant to make the database column not nullable

Answer (score 2):

Even though Hibernate MAY completely ignore @NotNull associated to an the Entity class' member/property, we still might need to use it because :-

- Since our Entity class instance will serve just as any other POJO (say before associated with persistent context), as per the business logic we might be sure that a particular property can never be null. To achieve this check we will need to use @NotNull