# @NotNull on default in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, nhibernate-mapping

I have MySql database with several tables. Every field in each table is not nullable. That's why I am forced to use `@NotNull` annotation to each field in all my Java classes marked with `@Entity`. Do I really have to do this or is there a way to tell JPA/Hibernate to treat every field NotNullable on default?

edit:
I am aware of `@Column(name="something", nullable=false)` too. But still, it doesn't solve any problem - you have to write `nullable=false`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no such possibility. `Not Nullable` constraint is not what you always expect from a field, although it is used quite often. It is convenient when you can look at the attribute definition and tell everything out of it, without addressing to some high-level settings like "every field should be `@NotNull`".

It would be rather confusing to see such entity definition with this setting hidden elsewhere.

And, one more thing. `@NotNull` annotation and `@Column(name="something", nullable=false)` are not the same. More details here :
[Confusion: @NotNull vs @Column(nullable = false)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439504/confusion-notnull-vs-columnnullable-false)

Comment: Ah, I wanted to set `@NotNull` for every fields by default