# Eclipselink: JPA's DELETE FROM statement includes comparison to CLOB

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have an element collection on my class:

```
public class InstancePdo implements Comparable<InstancePdo> {

  @Id
  @Column(name = COLUMN_NAME_ID, columnDefinition = "UUID")
  private UUID id;

  @Id
  @Column(name = COLUMN_NAME_VERSION, columnDefinition = "int")
  private int version = -1;

  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @CollectionTable(name = "settings", joinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_NAME_ID, referencedColumnName = COLUMN_NAME_ID, nullable = false, updatable = true),
      @JoinColumn(name = "COLUMN_NAME_VERSION", referencedColumnName = COLUMN_NAME_VERSION, nullable = false, updatable = true) })
  private Set<SettingPdo> settings;
}
```

Now, the setting looks like this:

```
@Embeddable
@Table(
    name = "settings",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
        columnNames = { "id", "version", "key", "type" }))
public class SettingPdo implements Comparable<SettingPdo> {

  @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
  private String type;

  @Column(name = "key", nullable = false)
  private String key;


  @Column(name = "value", columnDefinition = "CLOB NOT NULL", )
  @Lob
  @Convert(converter = JsonNodeStringConverter.class)
  private String value;
}
```

Now, from time to time if I replace an instancePDO with a Merge operation, a delete statement is generated like this:

```
Error Code: 932
Call: DELETE FROM settings WHERE ((((((key = ?)) AND (type = ?)) AND (value = ?)) AND (id = ?)) AND (version = ?))
        bind => [4 parameters bound]
```

Now, the problem is that Oracle does not accept a WHERE clause on a CLOB (or any other LOB) column. I drained all stack overflow reading all similar threads like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33833399/1549977

> If you use a Set and make the element Column be not null, then
>   hibernate will make a primary key with the join column and element
>   column.

As you can see, Eclipselink will still generate delete statements which contains comparisons on a CLOB field.

Hashcode an equals are also correct.

I have no idea what to do next. What's wrong with my classes (or database, for that matter)? As I am stuck with Oracle, how can I force JPA not to include some specific columns in a delete statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I mean, I always thought that on change all items from the element connection get deleted and re-inserted. Why does JPA try to delete specific elements here? And if so, why try to use it's value?

Comment: Check that you are using the latest EclipseLink and that the target database platform is set (https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_target_database.htm ). This occurs because elements of the collection don't have an id to use to determine which to delete. You could workaround it by making the target an entity

Comment: I'm using IBM liberty profile and open liberty, so no choice about updating. As an entity or works. But it is not an entity imho. I could create a PMR of you think this is a bug.