# Spring Boot & Hibernate. Date auto-create

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I use Spring Boot annotaion @Entity to auto-create database fields.
So, i've tried this

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
public class Application {
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private Date date;
}
```

But Spring Boot makes 'date' typeof DATETIME in MySQL, so it's add time (00:00:00) to my row.
How can I fix this?

And another question. I have User.class

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
public class User implements UserDetails {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
```

}

But every field of this is nullable, so should I add an annotation `@Column(nullable = false)` to every field to makes it not null? It looks so dumb.

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String first_name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String last_name;
```

}

Comment: is there a good reason why you use `Date` and not `LocalDate`?
and regarding the `@Column(nullable=false)`, this might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439504/confusion-notnull-vs-columnnullable-false

Comment: Actually no, i can use `LocalDate` will it helps me?

Comment: @ClaudiuGuja Thanks, `LocalDate` works fine! Can you add an answer to let me accept this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Date`, it would be better to use `LocalDate` from Java8. This way, no time data should be stored in the database.

And regarding `@Column(nullable=false)`, this might be of help:
[Confusion: @NotNull vs @Column(nullable = false)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439504/confusion-notnull-vs-columnnullable-false)

Answer (score 0):

Properties are nullable by default in JPA, except primitive types. No need to add `@Column(nullable = true)` for `String` type

```
//default = nullable
@Column
private String prop;
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use pattern parameter instead of iso parameter :  `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")`

Comment: Nah, it still creates DATETIME instead of DATE