Exception is not thrown when it should thrown in Spring Boot test
There is an object and I want to test it with null parameters which should @notnull. I expect the test method throw exception but it did not. I am using auto configured H2 as a test database.
@Transactional
@Test
public void expect_save_cameraWithNullName_throwsException() {

    // arrange
    camera.setCameraName(null);

    // act and assert
    Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(() ->
            transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
                cameraRepository.save(camera);
                return null;
            })
    ).isInstanceOf(DataIntegrityViolationException.class);
}


I tried to use fixed database and also I was not using TransactionTemplate initially. Also I tried to throw any exception rather than DataIntegrityViolationException to see if any exception the application throws but there was no exception where should be.

Really, your question is, "why doesn't cameraRepository.save(camera) throw an exception?" which leads to the question, what would be checking that data integrity?  Perhaps this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439504/confusion-notnull-vs-columnnullable-false-with-jpa-and-hibernate

I marked it as @NotNull in the database and in the entity class so I think it should throw exception.

If yo do it out of a test (in the main src/java folder) without the assertion you get the same behaviour? Annotations are a pain in the sense that they may not always behave the same depending on context

I did it out of test and the exception occurred as expected @RaulLapeiraHerrero

So the test annotation is introducing some behavior that (to me) is counterintuitive... ummm, no idea pal, the only thing I can think of is debugging the annotation support classes from the testing lib which you are using...
