# Bidirectional one-to-one relation fails on saving if @NotNull used

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I've the following one-to-one relation between `User` and `UserSetup` entities:

```
@Entity
class User {

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", optional = false, cascade = ALL)
   private UserSetup setup;

   public User() {
      this.setup = new UserSetup(this);
   }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class UserSetup {

    @OneToOne(cascade = ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private User user;

    public UserSetup(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

It all works well, however if I add `@NotNull` to `setup` field in `User` class and call `save` on `User` repository it fails with:

> Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing
>   the transaction   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:77)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:71)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
>     ... 64 more Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException:
>   Validation failed for classes [User] during
>   update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ] List of
>   constraint violations:[
>     ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null',
>   propertyPath=setup, rootBeanClass=class User,
>   messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'} ]

What's going on? In debugger I see that `setup` field is set. Or maybe `@NotNull` should not be used with `@OneToOne` but `optional` should be used instead?

Comment: Is the column created with `not null`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, yes, the column has not-null constraint.

Comment: How are the `ID`s created for both entities?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, they are taken from sequence and `@Id` along with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)` are used.

Comment: You use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` when it is actually `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I may change it - does it affect the problem with `@NotNull` in you opinion?

Comment: Well, I doubt that hibernate can create an ID if the generation type is wrong. This would mean, that it can't create a new `UserSetup` which is connected to the `User`

Comment: I'll try `SEQUENCE` however I doubt if it matters. Will let you know @XtremeBaumer.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer it doesn't work with `SEQUENCE` at all. It fails at start of the context.

Comment: With which error message?

Comment: With `PersitenceContext` creation error.

Comment: Can you post your configuration files?

Comment: I've almost no configuration files, everything is annotation-based.

Comment: Well, you still have to create the `PersitenceContext` with some data

Comment: No, it's created with springboot under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of how works Hibernate, that might not be possible, as Hibernate has to save one of the objects first, and when saving the first object the second one cannot be referenced in the database.

What you can do is put the `@NotNull` annotation to the `setup` field in the `User` class, as I understand you may not want to create a `User` without any setup, and the cascading would take care of removing the linked `UserSetup` object in case you remove the `User`.

Comment: I don't get it. I already put `@NotNull` and it does not work as I stated in the question.

Comment: Sorry I mean put `@NotNull` in `User` class but remove it in `UserSetup` class.

Comment: I've never had setup like this.

Comment: Remove `nullable = false` from UserSetup

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, `@Notnull` can not be used in User for UserSetup. That is because, User needs to be created first, and then the same user's ID would be used to save UserSetup as there is a foreign key constraint on it. Even though code wise, it is looking okay, involvement of DB to create the ID is one important factor here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is that what you think or you know for sure?

Comment: It is what I think. Having nullable = false in `@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)` in UserSetup class makes sense, but having @NotNull for UserSetup in User class seems to create a catch-22 situation.

Comment: So you suggest that having either `@NotNull` or `nullable = false` on one side, makes sense?

Comment: Not exactly, there is a slight difference between these two ways. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2726224/945214 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/7439544/945214